# java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax;

Tags: mysql, sql, netbeans

> Error: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL
>   syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version
>   for the right syntax to use near 'dc, customerdata cd WHERE
>   dc.location = '2' AND cd.username = 'jasmin" at line 1

```
    String dressLoc = dressno;
    String nameRenter = jLabel1.getText();

    String sql = "INSERT INTO orderdata (dressname,price,currentrenter,stat"
            + ",datereserve) SELECT dressname, price, concat(concat(fname,"
            + "' '), lname)AS currentrenter, 'Reserve', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP" 
            + "FROM dresscatalog dc, customerdata cd WHERE dc.location = ? "
            + "AND cd.username = ?";
    try
    {
        pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        pst.setString(1,dressLoc);
        pst.setString(2,nameRenter);
        pst.executeUpdate();


    }
    catch(SQLException ex)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, ex);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You miss a blank between `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` and `FROM`

```
 + "' '), lname)AS currentrenter, 'Reserve', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP " 
        + "FROM dresscatalog
```

And i guess you miss the join condition. In the Moment you get a carthesian product